# XAML Calendar Control for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows Phone Programming. I am in need of XAML Calendar Control with the following features and functionality supported.

- Month View & Week View - Capable of handling the click event on any particular given date. And the scroll left and right needed to show the previous and next month / week depending upon the view. Exactly as the calendar app in Windows Phone 8.1

Could you please suggest me links to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest **Syncfusion XAML controls for Windows Phone**.

They have an excellent Calendar control with month view. Scroll buttons are there for navigating to next/previous month. But I am not sure about week view. Please go through the following link for more details.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/calendar

Comment: @AniketKulkarni i have updated my answer. SivaSu has asked to suggest links. That's why i have posted link alone. Down voting totally disappoints :(